# WPF: Самый простой способ вызывать метод сочетанием клавиш

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я просмотрел много вопросов и ответов на англоязычном Stack Overflow, но так и не нашел ответа на вопрос: как вызывать какой-либо метод с помощью сочетания клавиш в WPF-приложениях? В `Windows Forms Application` это делалось довольно просто, но похоже в более развитом WPF это гораздо сложнее.

Ниже представлен классический пример. Нигде, где я смотел, толком не объяснено, что именно мы привязываем. Но это явно не метод. Что это вообще за `ApplicationCommands`?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
              Gesture="CTRL+R" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

В другом вопросе было сказано: *"XAML - это язык разметки, а потому мы не можем так просто вызвать метод оттуда"*. Хорошо, почему мы тогда с лёгкостью можем привязать метод к кнопке?

```
<Button 
    x:Name="SomeButton"
    Click="OnClickBtn1"/>
```

И, собственно, пример для вопроса. Всё, что нужно сделать - это вызвыать метод `OnClickBtn1` комбинацией клавиш (ну, например, `Ctrl+H`) наиболее простым способом. То есть, при нажатии этой комбинации клавиш будет тот же эффект, что и при клике кнопки `Btn1`. Приведённого ниже кода недостаточно для того, чтобы сочетание клавиш работало. Чего именно не хватает?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainDisplay" 
        <!-- ... --->
>

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+H" Command="{Binding OnClickBtn1}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <!-- ... -->

    <Button x:Name="Btn1"
    Width="70" 
    Content="Button" 
    Click="OnClickBtn1"/>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void OnClickBtn1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Была нажата кнопка Btn1 либо сочетание клавиш Ctrl+H");
    }

}
```

Comment: Первый метод — правильный.

Comment: Вас должен интересовать не самый простой, а самый правильный метод.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с командами (интерфейс `ICommand`) и шаблоном MVVM, всё станет понятно.

Comment: Также на шаблоне MVVM, но уже с использованием стороннего
[фреймворка](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL/pages/18972710/CommandManager+and+command+containers+Application-wide+commands)

Comment: Благодарю Всех за комментарии, но всё же: как решить поставленную задачу, приведённую во второй половине вопроса? Использование сторонних фреймворков заказчиком не одобрено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на твой вопрос:

**UserCommands.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Wpf_CommandsWithBindings
{
    public static class UserCommands
    {
        static UserCommands()
        {
            // Можно прописать горячие клавиши по умолчанию
            InputGestureCollection inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
            inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+S"));

            SomeCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Some", "SomeCommand", typeof(UserCommands), inputs);
        }

        public static RoutedCommand SomeCommand { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="Wpf_CommandsWithBindings.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_CommandsWithBindings"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="local:UserCommands.SomeCommand" Gesture="Ctrl+H" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:UserCommands.SomeCommand" Executed="ShowMessage_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Wpf_CommandsWithBindings
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowMessage_Executed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Test");
        }
    }
}
```

> Что это вообще за ApplicationCommands?

В `WPF` есть набор заготовленных комманд, которые не содержат никакого конкретного кода (что-то делающего полезное). Эти команды представляют общую задачу приложения, например, открыть папку, печать документа, открытие документа и т.д. То есть просто "задача" без конкретной реализации. Для выполнения конкретных действий командой, нужно использовать привязку, которая будет в коде вызывать конкретное действие. Может возникнуть вопрос, зачем нужны вообще эти заготовленные команды? Например, если сторонний разработчик создаст элемент управления `DirectoryView`, то такой элемент управления может внутри своей логики использовать команду `ApplicationCommands.Open` для вызова кода, открывающего корневую папку. По идее, если у тебя уже есть привязка для этой команды, то при использовании элемента управления уже не нужно ничего дописывать.

**Пример**, из которого видно, что достаточно прописать команду в элементе управления и в зависимости от места использования этого элемента будут выполняться разные действия (в данном примере демонстрация, что это вообще работает):

**UserControlTest.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Wpf_CommandsWithBindings.UserControlTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_CommandsWithBindings"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    Background="#FFE8EDF9"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Content="Test" Height="21" MinWidth="45" Margin="15,0,15,0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="Wpf_CommandsWithBindings.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_CommandsWithBindings"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Executed="ShowMessage_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControlTest />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Wpf_CommandsWithBindings
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowMessage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Test");
        }
    }
}
```

> Хорошо, почему мы тогда с лёгкостью можем привязать метод к кнопке?

Потому что в XAML окна прописано пространство имён

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

и класс, относящийся к этому XAML

```
x:Class="Wpf_CommandsWithBindings.MainWindow"
```

Comment: Я не могу подобрать нужные слова, чтобы выразить Вам благодарность за Ваши объяснения и Ваше потраченное время.

Comment: Простите, возможно Вы пропустили `RoutedUICommand` при объявлени `SomeCommand`? И ещё, куда следует поместить класс `UserCommands.cs`? У меня пишет, что в пространстве имён `clr-namespace:Wpf_CommandsWithBindings` отсутствует имя `UserCommands`. Это значит, класс `UserCommands.cs` не обнаруживается в текущей директории.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите.

Есть несколько методов «подцепить» клавиатурные команды к коду. Примитивный метод — навесить обработчик `OnKeyDown`/`Up` на ваше окно, и в code-behind проверять нужную клавишу.

Этот метод плох тем, что он недекларативен (вам нужно заглянуть в обработчик, чтобы понять, какая именно комбинация клавиш используется), и тем, что действие происходит в code-behind, то есть, во View-коде, а не в VM, где ему и полагается быть. Если вы не пользуетесь MVVM и пишете всю логику в классе окна, вторая может и не представлять проблемы.

Затем, команды. Они нужны для того, чтобы иметь повторно используемое обозначение для действия («открыть файл», «начать воспроизведение», «закрыть документ» и т. д.). Для некоторых действий есть стандартные команды (находящиеся в классе [`ApplicationCommands`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx), а также других, например, [`EditingCommands`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)), недостающие команды вы можете легко определить самостоятельно. Команды можно вызывать из многих мест (горячие клавиши, кнопка на тулбаре, меню, ...). Ваш код с `KeyBinding` привязывает в окне горячую клавишу <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd> к команде `ApplicationCommands.Open`.

Теперь, реакция на команды. Для того, чтобы привязать свой обработчик к одной из стандартных команд (наподобие `ApplicationCommands.Open`), вы должны использовать `CommandBinding`. Если обработчик находится в классе окна, можно использовать разметку наподобие

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
                    Executed="ExecuteOpen" CanExecute="CanExecuteOpen" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Если обработчик находится в VM, вы должны передать ваши `CommandBinding`'и из VM в окно.

Если же ваша команда «самописная», вам не нужно подцеплять к ней обработчик, он уже и так там есть.

---

Код `Command="{Binding OnClickBtn1}"` работать не будет, т. к. `OnClickBtn1` — это, скорее всего, метод, а значением `Command` должна быть команда (то есть, объект, реализующий интерфейс `ICommand`).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ и за Ваше время!